# Trees with values on the leaves only

Tags: haskell, tree, binary-tree

A few years ago, during a C# course I learned to write a binary tree that looked more or less like this:

```
data Tree a = Branch a (Tree a) (Tree a) | Leaf
```

I saw the benefit of it, it had its values on the branches, which allowed for quick and easy lookup and insertion of values, because it would encounter a value on the root of each branch all the way down until it hit a leaf, that held no value.

[image: Each circle with a number is a Branch]

Ever since I started learning Haskell, however; I've seen numerous examples of trees that are defined like this:

```
data Tree a = Branch (Tree a) (Tree a) | Leaf a
```

That definition puzzles me. I can't see the usefulness of having data on the elements that **don't** branch, because it would end up leading to a tree that looks like this:

[image: The circles with numbers are Leaf nodes]

Which to me, seems like a poorly designed alternative to a List. It also makes me question the lookup time of it, since it can't asses which branch to go down to find the value it's looking for; but rather needs to go through every node to find what it's looking for.

So, can anyone shed some light on why the second version (value on leaves) is so much more prevalent in Haskell than the first version?

Comment: sure you can do that in C#, and it's fairly easy too; if you know how anyway

Comment: They are simply two different data structures with perhaps different uses, advantages, disadvantages (and perhaps not). For example, `Data.IntMap` is of the latter form (data only on leaves) and `Data.Map` is of the former. What's the point of having both? The documentation has this to say: "[IntMap] performs especially well on binary operations like union and intersection. However, my benchmarks show that it is also (much) faster on insertions and deletions when compared to [Data.Map]". Finally, I wouldn't say the second version is "much more prevalent".

Answer (score 8):

I think this depends on what you're trying to model and how you're trying to model it.

A tree where the internal nodes store values and the leaves are just leaves is essentially a standard binary tree (tree each leaf as `NULL` and you basically have an imperative-style binary tree). If the values are stored in sorted order, you now have a binary search tree. There are many specific advantages to storing data this way, most of which transfer directly over from imperative settings.

Trees where the leaves store the data and the internal nodes are just for structure do have their advantages. For example, red/black trees support two powerful operations called `split` and `join` that have advantages in some circumstances. `split` takes as input a key, then destructively modifies the tree to produce two trees, one of which contains all keys less than the specified input key and one containing the remaining keys. `join` is, in a sense, the opposite: it takes in two trees where one tree's values are all less than the other tree's values, then fuses them together into a single tree. These operations are particularly difficult to implement on most red/black trees, but are much simpler if all the data is stored in the leaves only rather than in the internal nodes. [This paper detailing an imperative implementation of red/black trees](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.109.4875&rep=rep1&type=pdf) mentions that some older implementations of red/black trees used this approach for this very reason.

As another potential advantage of storing keys in the leaves, suppose that you want to implement the concatenate operation, which joins two lists together. If you don't have data in the leaves, this is as simple as

```
concat first second = Branch first second
```

This works because no data is stored in those nodes. If the data is stored in the leaves, you need to somehow move a key from one of the leaves up to the new concatenation node, which takes more time and is trickier to work with.

Finally, in some cases, you might want to store the data in the leaves because the leaves are fundamentally different from internal nodes. Consider a parse tree, for example, where the leaves store specific terminals from the parse and the internal nodes store all the nonterminals in the production. In this case, there really are two different types of nodes, so it doesn't make sense to store arbitrary data in the internal nodes.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I can see it in the case of a parse tree, where, say an operator is the branch, and an operand is the leaf; I still, however can't see the benefit of having a data tree with the data in the leaves, you'd just end up having this giant tree containing no data at all, and then a bunch of data at the end. Wouldn't doing that hurt lookup time like crazy? and wouldn't it then just be better to use a normal list?

Comment: @ElectricCoffee I think that depends on what you want to do. If you're not storing elements in sorted order, you could either have a rigidly-prescribed structure for the trees (for example, perfect binary trees) and then look up individual elements by index by using math on the sizes of those trees. This is actually sometimes done in practice; check out skew binomial random access lists for an example. If you're trying to make a BST, though, it's definitely not a good idea to store the elements purely in the leaves without leaving some auxiliary data up in the nodes.

Comment: @ElectricCoffee A Huffman tree is all about paths taken through the tree. The nodes don't need anything other than pointers to their children. It's just one of many example of a use case where the nodes don't need data.

Comment: @ElectricCoffee, "giant tree containing no data at all, and then a bunch of data at the end": as can be seen from your diagrams in the question, the set of leaves is more "giant" than the rest of the tree.

Answer (score 5):

You described a tree with data at the leaves as "a poorly designed alternative to a List."

I agree that this could be used as an alternative to a list, but it's not necessarily poorly designed! Consider the data type

```
data Tree t = Leaf t | Branch (Tree t) (Tree t)
```

You can define `cons` and `snoc` (append to end of list) operations -

```
cons :: t -> Tree t -> Tree t
cons t (Leaf s)     = Branch (Leaf t) (Leaf s)
cons t (Branch l r) = Branch (cons t l) r

snoc :: Tree t -> t -> Tree t
snoc (Leaf s)     t = Branch (Leaf s) (Leaf t)
snoc (Branch l r) t = Branch l (snoc r t)
```

These run (for roughly balanced lists) in O(log n) time where n is the length of the list. This contrasts with the standard linked list, which has O(1) `cons` and O(n) `snoc` operations. You can also define a constant-time `append` (as in templatetypedef's answer)

```
append :: Tree t -> Tree t -> Tree t
append l r = Branch l r
```

which is O(1) for two lists of any size, whereas the standard list is O(n) where n is the length of the left argument.

In practice you would want to define slightly smarter versions of these functions which attempt to keep the tree balanced. To do this it is often useful to have some additional information at the branches, which could be done by having multiple kinds of branch (as in a red-black tree which has "red" and "black" nodes) or explicitly include additional data at the branches, as in

```
data Tree b a = Leaf a | Branch b (Tree b a) (Tree b a)
```

For example, you can support an O(1) `size` operation by storing the total number of elements in both subtrees in the nodes. All of your operations on the tree become slightly more complicated since you need to correctly persist the information about subtree sizes -- in effect the work of computing the size of the tree is amortized over all the operations that construct the tree (and cleverly persisted, so that minimal work is done whenever you need to reconstruct a size later).

Comment: it's all very nice that adding branches to the tree is easier with this kind of list; I just can't see what good that would do if the branches themselves don't contain any data. Why add more data-less branches? Doesn't it just unnecessarily increase the size of the tree?

Comment: Note that this data type includes (non-empty) linked lists as a subset, since you could just set all the left-hand branches to be `Leaf a`. So this data structure is capable of doing anything a regular linked list can do (and also it has fast access to the last element, fast snoc, fast append etc).

The non-empty list is `data List a = Leaf a | Branch a (List a)` -- would you say that this has data at the branches? If so, then in a sense the tree with data at the leaves also has data at the branches (it's just that the data is in the form of another tree).

Answer (score 1):

More is <del>better</del> <del>worse</del> more. I'll explain just a couple *basic* considerations to show why your intuition fails. The general idea, though, is that different data structures need different things.

Empty leaf nodes can actually be a space (and therefore time) problem in some contexts. If a node is represented by a bit of information and two pointers to its children, you'll end up with two null pointers per node whose children are both leaves. That's two machine words per leaf node, which can add up to quite a bit of space. Some structures avoid this by ensuring that each leaf holds at least one piece of information to justify its existence. In some cases (such as [ropes](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/rope)), each leaf may have a fairly large and dense payload.

Making internal nodes bigger (by storing information in them) makes it more expensive to modify the tree. Changing a leaf in a balanced tree typically forces you to allocate replacements for `O(log n)` internal nodes. If each of those is larger, you've just allocated more space and spent extra time to copy more words. The extra size of the internal nodes also means that you can fit less of the tree *structure* into the CPU cache.